# Is it possible to fetch Social Comments using CAML query?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is it possible to fetch the Social Comments using CAML query instead of using SocialCommentManager. If it is possible then can anyone provide me the syntax.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CAML queries can only be used against SharePoint lists, those can only be accessed via the SharePoint object model.